# ggplot's stat_ecdf adds two extra points

Tags: r, ggplot2

In `ggplot2`, when I try to plot cumulative density function using `stat_ecdf` and with `geom_point`, I see a strange behavior: two extra points are added to my numbers, one before everything, and another one after everything else. This kind of make sense if the default `geom_step` was used for plotting, but with `geom_point`, this is very confusing if not outright wrong. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is an example:

```
qplot(a,data=data.frame(a=1:10),stat="ecdf",geom="point")
```

which produces:

[image: ecdf plot with one point extra point at zero and one at one]

Note the extra points at 0 and at 10.

Here is my R session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)
... 
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
other attached packages:
[1] scales_0.2.4  ggplot2_1.0.0
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't much sense to apply a `stat_cdf` to `geom_point()`. If you want a CDF plot, you are better off with.

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(a=1:10)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=a)) + stat_ecdf() + scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:11)
```

[image]

`stat_ecdf` is supposed to be a step function.

If you insist on making your code work and would accept a hack-around, then you can do this.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=a)) + geom_point(stat = "ecdf", colour = c(rep("red", 11), NA))
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why you say points don't make sense for ecdf. Points are sufficient to see the distribution, and they make it easy to see what exact values were measured. I opened a issue for this on [github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1000). If my suggested solution was not adopted, I will accept this answer. Also, note it should be `ggplot(data = df, aes(x=a)) + geom_point(stat = "ecdf", colour = c(NA,rep("red", 10), NA))` because the first point is also an addition.

Comment: For me, I don't like how F(x) is not defined for all x∈R. What is F(0.5) on an geom_point cdf?

Comment: If the random variable being plotted is discrete, it doesn't make sense to have values for all x∈R. In fact, for discrete variables, it doesn't make sense to have step functions at all, but ECDF is still a valid thing to look at and points are appropriate. See [wiki of cdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).

Comment: 'pad = FALSE' should do a job.